# Typing: incompatible type when declare typing.Type[]

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

For the following code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import typing


class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

class D(A):
    pass

class E(A):
    pass

MAPPING_X = {
    B: 'b',
    C: 'c',
}
MAPPING_Y = {
    D: 'd',
    E: 'e',
}

all_mappings = {}  # type: typing.Dict[typing.Type[A], str]
all_mappings.update(MAPPING_X)
all_mappings.update(MAPPING_Y)
```

mypy return following errors (python 3.4):

```
t.py:30: error: Argument 1 to "update" of "dict" has incompatible type Dict[type, str]; expected Mapping[Type[A], str]
t.py:31: error: Argument 1 to "update" of "dict" has incompatible type Dict[type, str]; expected Mapping[Type[A], str]
```

I don't understand how specify i want subclases of `A` as Dict keys. How to declare type ?

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding how the `typing` and `mypy` modules work, but there seems to be some kind of bug going on here. If I do this (example adapted from the `typing.Type` section of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#classes-functions-and-decorators)):

```
import typing

class User(): pass
class BasicUser(User): pass

def make_new(u: typing.Type[User]) -> User:
    return u()

x = make_new(BasicUser)
```

There is no `mypy` error. If I do this:

```
import typing

class A():
    pass

MAPPING_X = {
    A: 'a',
}
all_mappings = {}  # type: typing.Dict[typing.Type[A], str]
all_mappings.update(MAPPING_X)
```

There is also no error. However, this does produce the `mypy` error:

```
import typing

class A():
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

MAPPING_X = {
    A: 'a',
    B: 'b',
}

all_mappings = {}  # type: typing.Dict[typing.Type[A], str]
all_mappings.update(MAPPING_X)
```

Based upon my understanding of the documentation, this error shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing this correctly, but it is required to declare the types for the `MAPPING_X` and `MAPPING_Y` first. This fixes the problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import typing

class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

class D(A):
    pass

class E(A):
    pass

MAPPING_X = {}  # type: typing.Dict[typing.Type[A], str]
MAPPING_Y = {}  # type: typing.Dict[typing.Type[A], str]

MAPPING_X = {
    B: 'b',
    C: 'c',
}
MAPPING_Y = {
    D: 'd',
    E: 'e',
}

all_mappings = {}  # type: typing.Dict[typing.Type[A], str]
all_mappings.update(MAPPING_X)
all_mappings.update(MAPPING_Y)
```

No `mypy` errors.

However, it seems to me that your code as written should work, and that this is the symptom of a bug.